# How to properly prepare a column name if passed to a stored procedure?

Tags: php, plugin-development, mysql, wpdb, sql

I've figured out that I can use `%i` with `$wpd->prepare()` to escape identifiers like column names. The thing is that the query I'm preparing is a call to a stored procedure like this. I want the end result to be something like the following:

```
call get_select_preview('i_am_a_column_name');
```

This column_name is then used for a constructed query inside that stored procedure (Not prepared inside the procedure since you can't prepare identifiers in mysql as far as I know). I know preparing it as a string won't be enough. I NEED to prepare it as an identifier (which `$wpdb` supports with `%i` from what I am reading). The problem is that I need to prepare it as an identifier and pass it as a string. So I created the following class method:

```
    private function prepare_identifier_as_string($identifier) {
        $identifier = $this->DB->prepare("%i", $identifier);
        return str_replace('`', "'", $identifier);
    }
```

My question is:

**Will this suffice and are there better ways?**